# Add new record in retrieved from sql database list

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist

I need to add new record to list, which retrieved from database,-
It's seems be simpse to do, but how to connect(merge) these 2 methods:

```
public void addNewUser(){
    myList= new ArrayList<>();
    Values newValue = new Values(this.id, this.orderNo, this.productName, this.price, this.qty);
    newValue.setEditable(true);
    myList.add(newValue);
}
```

I retrieve list of users from sql database using such method:

```
private List<Values> valuesList;
private Values allValues;

private static List<Values> getUsers() {
    try {
        databaseConnection();
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM Registration";
        System.out.println("Retrieve values from Registration table...");
        PreparedStatement prepStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
        valuesList = new ArrayList<>();
        ResultSet resultSet = prepStatement.executeQuery();
        boolean found = false;
        while (resultSet.next() == true) {
            allValues = new Values();
            allValues.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            allValues.setOrderNo(resultSet.getString("orderNo"));
            allValues.setProductName(resultSet.getString("productName"));
            allValues.setPrice(resultSet.getBigDecimal("price"));
            allValues.setQty(resultSet.getInt("qty"));
            valuesList.add(allValues);
            found = true;
        }
        resultSet.close();
        prepStatement.close();
        close(connection);
        if (found) {
            return valuesList;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error in getUsers()-->" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return (null);
}

public List<Values> getInformation() {
    return getUsers();
}
```

Here my display page:

```
 <h:dataTable value="#{user.information}" var="x" border="1">
    <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Id"></h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
     <h:outputText value="#{x.id}"></h:outputText>
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Order No"></h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
     <h:inputText value="#{x.orderNo}" rendered="#{x.editable}"></h:inputText>
     <h:outputText value="#{x.orderNo}" rendered="#{not x.editable}"></h:outputText>
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Product name"></h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
     <h:inputText value="#{x.productName}" rendered="#{x.editable}"></h:inputText>
     <h:outputText value="#{x.productName}" rendered="#{not x.editable}"></h:outputText>
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Price"></h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
     <h:inputText value="#{x.price}" rendered="#{x.editable}"></h:inputText>
     <h:outputText value="#{x.price}" rendered="#{not x.editable}"></h:outputText>
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Quantity"></h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
     <h:inputText value="#{x.qty}" rendered="#{x.editable}"></h:inputText>
     <h:outputText value="#{x.qty}" rendered="#{not x.editable}"></h:outputText>
   </h:column>
 </h:dataTable>
 <h:commandButton value="AddNew" action="#{user.add}"></h:commandButton>
```

Comment: what is your problem, your question is a bit not clear?

Comment: You need to edit your post, to ask a specific question, to show the work that you've done so far in trying to answer it, and where you've got stuck.

Comment: I can't open 'adding' fields in the bottom of my list for entering new user!

Comment: so now you have a problem with your pages **xhml** not with your database?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add another values like your first method to your List then you can do like this :

```
//myList = new ArrayList<>(); you dont need to use this, this can empty your list

myList = getUsers();//get your List
Values newValue = new Values(this.id, this.orderNo, this.productName, this.price, this.qty);

//add a new element to your list
newValue.setEditable(true);
myList.add(newValue);
```

**N.B**

You have a problem in your **xhtml**:

```
<h:commandButton value="AddNew" action="#{user.add}"></h:commandButton>
```

So if you try to call the `addNewUser()` then this not work with you.

**Solution**

This can call your method `addNewUser()`

```
<h:commandButton value="AddNew" action="#{user.addNewUser}"></h:commandButton>
```

So after that :

You should to update your dataTable

```
<h:commandButton value="AddNew" action="#{user.addNewUser}" update="idOfYourDataTable"/>
```

Don't forgot to add an id to your dataTable:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{user.information}" var="x" border="1" id="idOfYourDataTable">

...
```

Another thing :

```
<h:dataTable value="#{user.information}"
```

Make sure you have a `List<Values> information` in your `managedBean`, because the code that you put, there are no List information.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: 1.<h:commandButton value="AddNew" action="#{user.add}"></h:commandButton>- I was unattentive my mistake,- experiment with another method. 2. List<Values> information - I use: public List<Values> getInformation() {
    return getUsers();
}

Comment: Thank you for your advices, trying to fix my mistakes!

Comment: @ZhadovetsIvan so what is your problem exactly? what you want to do, did you get any error? is my solution work with you or not?

Comment: I try open input fields at the bottom of the list, which I retreive from DB - private static List<Values> getUsers() {}; using - public List<Values> getInformation() {
    return getUsers();
} for displaying users list on xhtml page. So I create new List<Values> myList. In method addNewUser() get myList= getUsers(); create new object of Values: Values newValue = new Values(); newValue.setEditable(true);- to open 'input fields' for new user. Then myList.add(newValue); but nothing happen still and haven't any mistake! Also I add id for datatable and update for commandButton.What'd U think?